# extract chars from each line in specified order

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I want to extract Nth character with specific order using bash command.

For example,if sample.txt contains strings like below..

```
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
```

And my desired output is below.

```
BDC
BDC
BDC
BDC
```

But, when i use `cut -c 2,4,3 < sample.txt`, I got,

```
BCD
BCD
BCD
BCD
```

How can I preserve the order that I give? 
Is there any other command or script for this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some popular AWKs<sup>*</sup>, when field separator is the null string, each individual character becomes a field. Using this functionality you can easily extract selected characters in any order. E.g.:

```
$ awk -v FS= '{print $2$4$3}' file
BDC
BDC
BDC
BDC
```

<sup>*</sup> Like GAWK, MAWK, busybox AWK, OpenBSD AWK, etc.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` will do it quite handily using *capture groups* and *back references* with the standard `s/find/replace/` operation. For example:

```
sed 's/.\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).*$/\1\3\2/' file
```

Where `sed` uses `\(stuff\)` to capture `"stuff"` with basic regular expression syntax  in the `find` part and then uses the numbered back reference `\1` to reinsert what was captured in the `replace` part of the expression (`\2` for the 2nd back reference for the 2nd capture group, and so on). `'.'` matches any single character, and `'*'` is the repetition match for zero-or-more occurrences. `'$'` is the anchor for the end of line.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example data in `file`, you would have:

```
$ sed 's/.\(.\)\(.\)\(.\).*$/\1\3\2/' file
BDC
BDC
BDC
BDC
```

Both `sed` and the other `awk` solutions will be *Orders of Magnitude* faster than spawning a separate process/subshell for `cut` each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

With gawk or nawk:

```
awk -v FPAT='.' '{print $2$4$3}' file
```

Output:

```
BDC
BDC
BDC
BDC
```

From `man gawk`:

> `FPAT`: A regular expression describing the contents of the fields in a record.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields, where the fields match the regular expression, instead of using the value of the FS variable as the field separator.